# Difference between class object Method declaration React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have seen two ways of declaring methods inside a Class component in `React`

**Method 1**

```
class someComp extends React.Component  {  
    handleResetShapes = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({state: 'try'});
    }

    render() {}
}
```

**Method 2**

```
class someComp extends React.Component  {  
    handleResetShapes(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({state: 'try'});
    }

    render() {}
}
```

In that specific example `Method 1` worked and the other didn't. However I have seen methods declared as `Method 2` and it works fine, just can't provide an example now.

**Question**

What is the difference and what is that Javascript concept called?

Comment: `just can't provide an example now` Please post one, I'd be quite curious to see one where `this` refers to the instantiated object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method 1 is called [public class fields syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties), using it and we don't need to worry about the meaning of `this` in runtime because it's automatically bound. For example:

```
class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  // This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick.
  // Warning: this is *experimental* syntax.
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

---

In Method 2, it's just a normal method on the class, a common pattern is for an event handler when you define a component using an [ES6 class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

However, when using this method, you have to be careful about the meaning of `this` in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) by default. If you forget to bind `this.handleClick` and pass it to `onClick`, `this` will be **undefined** when the function is actually called.

```
class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>;
  }
}
```

---

The difference between method 1 and method 2 is about the meaning of `this` inside the function when the function is actually called.

---

Reference: [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in how 'this' is handled.

For Method 1, you are defining an arrow function within your class. 'this' will always be the lexical scope where the function is defined, in this case the class itself. That remains true regardless of how the function is called. This is very convenient for React event handlers.

For Method 2, you are defining a prototype function within the class. The value of 'this' depends on how the function is invoked. If it were invoked through an instance of the class, 'this' would be the class itself. However, when you reference the function in an event binding, it won't be invoked through the class instance. Instead it will be invoked directly. 'this' is undefined in this case.

For Method 2 to work, you would have to do the following:

```
class someComp extends React.Component  {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleResetShapes = this.handleResetShapes.bind(this);
  }

  handleResetShapes(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({state: 'try'});
  }

   render() {...}
}
```

This creates a new handleResetShapes function where the value of 'this' is permanently set to the class instance.

Other cases where Method 2 would work would be those that have no reference to 'this'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of them will work.
It depends how the methods are called when `event` is triggered.
For `Method1`:
`<button onClick={this.handleResetShapes}>...</button>`
For `Method2`:
`<button onClick={(e) => this.handleResetShapes(e)}>...</button>`