# React TypeError: undefined onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I get an undefined error in the following the clicking of the submit button in a login page. Here is the Login.js file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { login } from './StudentFunctions'


class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      errors: {}

    }

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const student = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }

    login(student).then(res => {
      if (!res.error) {
        this.props.history.push('/profile')

      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className = "col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
            <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <h1 className="h3 mb-3 front-weight-normal">Please sign in </h1>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Enter email"
                  value={this.state.email}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password"
                    className="form-control"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Enter Password"
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <button type="submit"
                className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
                  Sign in
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Login
```

And the function imported from StudentFunctinos.js is

```
export const login = student => {
  return axios
  .post('/TPMS/api/v1.0/student/login', {
    email: student.email,
    password: student.password

  })
  .then(res => {
    localStorage.setItem('usertoken', res.data)
    console.log(res)
    return res.data
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

The error is saying that e is undefined in the Login.js file, which throws the catch error. Is it because in the button html there is no declaration of what happens on the click:
`i.e onClick(e) => {this.onSubmit}`
or something like this?

Comment: Nope your configuration seems right, can you put some console.log to the onSubmit and login .then() to detect which part it gives the error, can it pass to the action the right value or crashes in the page

Comment: I elaborate the answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you applied the normal class method, which is handling `this` in a different way. it considers `this` with the context you call it, so in your case, you call it in an event binding(onSubmit), so it will not consider itself in the class and it will return undefined. My solution is using arrow functions, which uses this in a stable way, and always executes in the [lexical scope](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript#toc-lexical-scope), in this case, in the Class you call:

```
  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const student = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }

    login(student).then(res => {
      if (!res.error) {
        this.props.history.push('/profile')

      }
    })
  }
```

you can find more explanations in this question: [Difference between class object Method declaration React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846232/difference-between-class-object-method-declaration-react)

Also, I suggest this tutorial, which explains a lot about Javascripts unusual behaviors:

[Javascript the weird parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts)

Answer (score 0):

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const student = {email, password}

    login(student).then(res => {
      if (!res.error) {
        this.props.history.push('/profile')

      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how this answer will solve the problem, instead of posting code-only answer.

Comment: @ArunVinoth  I elaborate my answer, check it out