# React setState is not accessible within lambda function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to define a global state in a react project using `React.useContext` & `React.useState`.

I currently have something like this:

```
# GlobalState.js
class GlobalState extends AbstractState {
   register(current, setCurrent) {
      this.current = current
      this.setCurrent = setCurrent
   }
   ...
}

const globalState = new GlobalState()
export default globalState
```

And this is passed from App by something like:

```
const [current, setCurrent] = React.useState({})
globalState.register_state(current, setCurrent)
const state = {current: current, setCurrent: setCurrent}
return React.createElement(GlobalContext.Provider, {value: state},
    ...children
)
```

and it is used at some point as follows:

```
class WebRequestsTimeChart extends React.Component {

render(){
    ...
    return React.createElement(GlobalContext.Consumer, null, (state) => {
        return this.#getChart(state)
    })
}

componentDidMount() {
   console.log(GlobalState.setCurrent) // actual react dispatch content
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   console.log(GlobalState.setCurrent) // actual react dispatch content
}

#getChart(state) {
   console.log(GlobalState.setCurrent) // actual react dispatch content
   return React.createElement(VictoryChart, {
       ...
       containerComponent: React.createElement(VictoryZoomVoronoiContainer, {
           ...
           events: {
              onClick: (event) => {
                  console.log(state.setCurrent) // actual react dispatch content
                  console.log(GlobalState.setCurrent) // f(){} <--- ???
              }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

So somehow, lambda passed to onClick cannot access the `GlobalState.setCurrent` but it has no problem accessing `state.setCurrent`. If I define another method like `GlobalState.someRandomMethod`, this is still accessible by `onClick`. Somehow, `setCurrent` returned by `React.useState` seems to be behave differently. I also realized this method cannot be copied (eg. `structuredClone` doesn't work for that). Another thing I considered is [Difference between class object Method declaration React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846232/difference-between-class-object-method-declaration-react), but I'm not sure how this would cause `GlobalState.setCurrent` to behave differently.

adding below also doesn't change this behavior:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getChart = this.getChart.bind(this).bind(GlobalState);
    }
```

Please let me know if you have any idea on what is going on, and how I can use `GlobalState.setCurrent` inside `onClick`

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking, but why not consider Redux for handling global state? Make use of an existing and well-proven technology.

Comment: I'm considering it actually, just wanted to see what vanilla react implementation would look like to see if adding redux dependency would justify itself. (main point is I don't need most of the redux features, just a global state, so I thought those might introduce some additional memory/processing overhead if anything) but either way, I'll definitely take a closer look into it later on

Comment: redux is a minimal overhead - the only problem that you may find is that it gets overused due to how easy it is to read/write from the global store! Transient items should not be stored in redux, nor should stuff that is generally static (e.g. theming, translations). Context is perfect for those scenarions.

Answer (score 0):

`GlobalState.setCurrent` would be a [static method on the class itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static), which you haven't declared. It's not the same thing as a `setCurrent` instance method.

```js
class Foo {
  bar () {
    return 'bar';
  }
}

console.log(Foo.bar?.()); // undefined. "bar" doesn't exist on the class itself.

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar()) // 'bar'; exists on instance of Foo.

class Baz {
  static boom () {
    return "static boom";
  }
  
  boom () {
    return "instance boom";
  }
}

console.log(Baz.boom()); // static boom
const baz = new Baz();
console.log(baz.boom()); // instance boom
```

Comment: This seems close, but I don't understand few things. \
1- why would `GlobalState.setCurrent` would be `f(){}` rather than `undefined`? \
2- I'm not sure why it is still visible if I define another method the same way, (just not by using `setState` but some random lambda) 
\ I tried using `static staticSetCurrent`, set it like `this.constructor.staticSetCurrent = setCurrent`, and it is accessible though which is pretty good!

Comment: Edit, no this doesn't work as well, it seems like this.constructor.statisSetCurrent is again `f(){}`